# Android AlarmManager - Get AlarmID when alarm is triggered

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have an app that creates multiple alarms. Everything works fine, however, for some other functions (like updating a log) I need to retrieve the alarmID when the alarm is fired.

Here is the code the alarms are set with:

```
public void setAlarm(){
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(c,AlarmReceiver.class);
    intentAlarm.putExtra("userid", userid);
    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)  
    c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent; 
    alarmIntent  = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, alarmID, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeToMiliseconds(hour,minute),
           AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,alarmIntent);

   Toast.makeText(c,"Alarm set for " + toTime(hour,minute),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   Log.d("setAlarm()",alarm.toString());

}
```

The alarm receiver is an activity (which works fine). I just need to retrieve the alarms ID that's currently being fired.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer; 
    private String scanContent;
    private static final int ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 0;
    String userid;
    Button backBtn;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakelock;
    private ListView medBoxList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> medList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
         ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    /**
     * Wakeup device if it's sleeping
     */
     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         wakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
         wakelock.acquire();
         this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);


    Intent alarmActivityIntent = getIntent();
    userid =  alarmActivityIntent.getStringExtra("userid");
    playSound(this, getAlarmUri());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Take Medication", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Button stopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanQR);
    Button skipBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skipBtn);
    backBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backBtn); 
  //Click button to scan and update userlog

    //Click button to scan and update userlog
    stopAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            launchQRScanner();                  
        }
    });  

    //Click button to skip
   skipBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }); 
}
private void playSound(Context context, Uri alert) {
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("OOPS");
    }
}

//Get an alarm sound. Try for an alarm. If none set, try notification, 
//Otherwise, ringtone.
private Uri getAlarmUri() {
    Uri alert = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alert == null) {
        alert = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (alert == null) {
            alert = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        }
    }
    return alert;
}

public void launchQRScanner() {
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.QRCODE});
    startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    scanContent = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT);
    finish();
    if(scanContent != null){
        updateUserLog(scanContent);
        Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserlogListActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextScreen);  

    }
}

//Disable alarm with button instead of scan
public void alarmStopper(View v){
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserlogListActivity.class);
    startActivity(nextScreen);  
}
//TAKE MED ACTIVITY (MOVE TO )
public void updateUserLog(String scanContent){
     //Toast.makeText(this, "Adding Userlog = " + scanContent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(scanContent != null){

        String userid,medname,tabstaken,dob;

        //Break the scan content into strings for each variable
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scanContent, ",");
             dob = st.nextToken();
             medname = st.nextToken();
             tabstaken = st.nextToken();

         if(dob != "" && medname != "" && tabstaken != ""){
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                HashMap<String,String> userLog = new HashMap<String, String>();
                HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
                user = db.getUserDetails();

                //Store the userlog by passing to UserLogEntry
                userid = user.get("uid");

                if(userid != ""){
                    userLog = db.getNewestUserLogEntryForMed(medname);
                    String tabstr = userLog.get("tabsleft");
                    Log.d ("getNewestUserLogEntryForMed()", "medname " + userLog.get("medname") + " timetaken " 
                            + userLog.get("medtaken") + " Tabs - " + tabstr);
                    int tabs = Integer.parseInt(tabstr);
                    tabs = tabs - 1;
                    String tabsupdated = Integer.toString(tabs);
                    Log.d ("Tabs Updated - ", "medname " + userLog.get("medname") + " timetaken " 
                            + userLog.get("medtaken") + " Tabs - " + tabsupdated);
                    UserLogEntry userlog = new UserLogEntry(getApplicationContext(),userid,medname,tabsupdated);
                    userlog.addUserLog();
                    finish();
                }
         }

    }   

}
```

Any tips?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was staring me in the face. I can use bundle to pass whatever I need into the alarm intent. I already was passing the userid (incorrectly). I just have to remember whenever there is an intent, that I can use bundle to pass simple variables along with it.

```
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(c,AlarmReceiver.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("userid", userid);
extras.putInt("alarmID", alarmID);
extras.putString("userlogID", userlogID);
extras.putString("medname", medname);
intentAlarm.putExtras(extras);
```

I figured I'd answer my own question in case someone else needs to do something similar, but if this is not helpful a moderator can delete it.